# Single keystroke shortcut to undo autocorrect

Tags: macos, keyboard, autocorrect, undo-redo

Is it possible to quickly revert an autocorrect with a single keystroke or combination?  As described in [Shortcut to revert autocorrect change](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94165/shortcut-to-revert-autocorrect-change) , the "correct" way to do it is:

1. backspace
2. wait
3. down-arrow
4. enter
5. space

This is far too slow, and I often reflexively hit Command-Z instead, which has other unintended effects.

Are there other options, ideally without the use of backspace, arrows, or waiting?

Any advice welcome, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

<kbd>↑</kbd> up arrow after you type the word that autocorrects, but before hitting the spacebar.

This should dismiss the autocorrect without making the change in the first place.

Comment: Clever, and successful, if anticipated.  Unfortunately I rarely expect this before hitting spacebar, and a solution that would work after hitting the spacebar would be ideal.  Thank you!

Comment: I hear ya. Hope we can find a simpler solution.