# Cancel an autocorrect suggestion while typing

Tags: macos, autocorrect

When I am typing, OSX helpfully offers and inserts corrections for me.

However, sometimes I do not want these corrections, as they can ruin an otherwise flawless piece of writing (see the below example.)

Lifting my hands from the keyboard, gripping the mouse and then dragging the mouse across my frictious desk before contracting the muscles along my entire finger to squeeze the mouse and activate its clicking procedure actually takes a very long time.

How can I cancel autocorrect suggestions without needing to use my mouse?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get rid of the autocorrect suggestion works for me.

Comment: Since I remapped ESC to Caps lock for vim, this is now the fastest way for me to cancel autocorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Simple...
Up arrow  <kbd>↑</kbd>  then continue.

Comment: Beat you by 20 seconds. :P

Comment: I was under on word-count, first attempt :P

Comment: Yes, this is the perfect answer for me (I actually found it here already: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201110/150109 - but it was too late :P)